# Running Startup script in Docker

Tags: java, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have build docker image from below:

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Utkarsh Saraf"

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common \
    apt-utils \
    libxml2-dev \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    build-essential \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    openssh-server && \
    apt-get clean


WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/app/startup.sh"]
```

In startup.sh, following code contains:

```
java web-app.jar &
```

How to execute shell file.

Comment: the chmod is on start.sh and the CMD is on startup.sh maybe it is related. plus, what does the 'docker logs [container]' say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue & it resolved by just replace the

```
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
CMD ["startup.sh"]
```

by

```
 ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/app/startup.sh"]
```

your final dockerfile will be:

```sh
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Utkarsh Saraf"

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common \
    apt-utils \
    libxml2-dev \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    build-essential \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    openssh-server && \
    apt-get clean


# for enabling SSh in container ------------------------------#
EXPOSE 80 2222 3306 8081

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY start.sh start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/app/startup.sh"]
```

I hope  that this part can help you to resolve your issue

Comment: Any shebang needed to be added in sh file?

Comment: I think you don't need to add anything

Comment: If I have to run multiple lines in this script,then some modification needed such as  want to open ssh server: /usr/sbin/sshd

Comment: I think you can use docker exec and add what you want , else you can add your script and mounted as a volume when you modified it locally will be changed inside your container.